# Form of a number not divisible by x or y

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

In number theory.
What is the general method for generating the numbers that are not divisible by x and y.

For example to find the numbers that are not divisible by 3 and 5.
For example (6n+- 1) is the generator of numbers not divisible by 2 or 3.

Also how can i get the form of a perticular number like not divisible by 5.[1,2,3,4,6,7..]

A explanation would be appreciated  thanks

Comment: Use the Chinese remainder theorem to solve a congruence system.

Comment: For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z^+},$ with $1  < x,y$, $(xy + 1)$ is not divisible by either $x$ or $y$.  Further, if $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $k < x,y$, then $(xy +k)$ is not divisible by either $x$ or $y$.

Comment: If x=3 and y=5 then by ur given formula (15k+1) is not divisible by 3 or 5 but this doesn't give all numbers. Like 1, 2, 4, 7, . My question here was particularly of the form to generate all numbers not divisible by x and y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General method for $x$ and $y$:**

Step 1: Calculate $C = lcm(x,y)$.

Step 2: List all numbers from $1$ to $C-1$ that are not divisible by $x$ or $y$. Let's call this list $L$.

Step 3: The numbers that are not divisible by $x$ or $y$ have the form
$Cn+k$ where $k$ is in the list $L$.

**Example: $x=2,y=3$**

Step 1: $C = 6$.

Step 2: $L = (1,5)$.

Step 3: $6n+1$, $6n+5$.

**Example: $x=3,y=5$**

Step 1: $C = 15$.

Step 2: $L = (1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14)$.

Step 3: $15n+1$, $15n+2$, $15n+4$, $15n+7$, $15n+8$, $15n+11$, $15n+13$, $15n+14$.

Comment: Thanks . This is lot understandable. So there is no single form for generating number not divisble by 5 for example. Also 7 is not divisible by 3 or 5 but from ur method it is only achievable if u include both plus and minus signs.

Comment: No, you can get 7 by plugging n=0.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is another question: if i want to find the form of the square of a number not divisible by 2 or 3 then from ur method it comes as 12k + 1 which good  but also the 12k + 25. But if k = -1 then it equals 13 which is not the number of any square.  Where am i wrong?

Comment: How did you get $12k+1$?

Comment: Lcm(2,3) +1 = (6k+1)  squaring it (6k+1)² = 36k²+12k+1 = 12k(3k+1) +1 = 12n +1 is the form of the square of a number not divisible by 2 or 3

Comment: So $n$ cannot be $-1$, because you can't solve $k(3k+1) = -1$ for $k$

Answer (score 0):

let $x,y \neq 1, -1$ and $k=lcd(x,y)$ then $kn+1$ is not divisble by both $x$ and $y$

proof: Assume that $kn+1$ is divisible with $x$ then terhe exists a $z \in Z$ such that

$kn+1=zx \Rightarrow zx-kn=1$

$k=lcd(x,y) \Rightarrow x|kn$

$x|k$ and $x| zx \Rightarrow x|zx-kn=1$ which means $x=1 $ or $-1$

Contradiction!!

proposition can be proved for $y$ by same method